# assign values to columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a temporary dataframe **temp** (as shown below) sliced from a larger dataframe.

[image]

I appreciate it if help me to assign the **item_price** value of each row to a related column associated with **model** as shown below:

[image]

Note: original and larger dataframe contains brands, prices and models which some of the rows have a similar brand name with different model and price, so I slice those similar records into **temp** dataframe and try to assign price to related columns associated with **model** for each record.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would delete the columns 'Sedan', 'Sport' and 'SUV' and use [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

In your case you would want to do the following:

Create a new Dataframe called df1 like so:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='brand', columns='model', values='item_price')
```

And then join your original DataFrame df1 with df1.

```
df = df.join(df1, on='brand')
```

This will give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: The resulting dataframe become reshaped based on the **model**, however it contains **NaN** value. for example index 317 has **NaN** value for SUV and Sport.

Comment: As I've edited my answer, you can set `index` to 'brand' and now your resulting dataframe will be like you wanted it

Comment: After using reset_index(), it returns only the return dataframe with one record. columns are: ['brand', 'SUV', 'Sedan', 'Sport'], and values are ['BMW', 90.0, 78.0, 83.0].

Comment: It's important to keep other rows and columns for further process.

Comment: Edited again, now it is exactly like your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and for introducing new methods to me. It works as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that returns the value based on a condition like this:

I'm using `df` as the name of the dataframe, you can rename to `temp`.

```py
def set_item_price(model):
  if model == "Sedan":
    return 78.00

  return 0

df["item_price"] = [
  set_item_price(a) for a in df['model']
]
```